# Scale child div to parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]I have a parent container `div a` with `display: grid` containing child containers `div b`, `div c`, etc. in a grid layout. How can I scale a child container to grow to the size of the parent container when hovering over the corresponding one? The resizing should be animated. Among others I have tried to change to absolute position on hover, but since the `position` property cannot be animated this didn't work for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: because grid's positioning can't be accsessed through css I don't think this is possible without js or very janky css selectors

Comment: Can you share the code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Good illustration aside (very useful), you are best off to include relevant styles that you already have tried using -- the layout won't look like you illustrated with just `display: grid`, you will need to disclose the additional rules you have there, with exception of those that you deem irrelevant. Basically, we expect you to include a minimal example that illustrates your issue, and can then help you point out what is wrong and how to rectify the issue that answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

I've made 2 methods of doing this, one with pure css and one with JS aswell.

#### CSS only

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> grid expand </title>
        <style>
            .grid {
                border: 1px solid black;
                width: 80vw;
                height: 80vw;
                text-align: center;
                position: relative;
            }
            .grid > * {
                outline: 1px solid black;
                margin: 5vw;
                position: absolute;
                width: 10vw;
                height: 10vw;
                transition: left 0.5s ease, top 0.5s ease, width 0.5s ease, height 0.5s ease;
                background: white;
            }
            .grid > *:nth-child(4n) {
                left: 75%;
            }
            .grid > *:nth-child(4n - 1) {
                left: 50%;
            }
            .grid > *:nth-child(4n - 2) {
                left: 25%;
            }
            .grid > *:nth-child(4n - 3) {
                left: 0;
            }
            .grid > *:nth-child(-n + 16) { 
                top: 75%; 
            }
            .grid > *:nth-child(-n + 12) { 
                top: 50%; 
            } 
            .grid > *:nth-child(-n + 8) { 
                top: 25%; 
            } 
            .grid > *:nth-child(-n + 4) {
                top: 0;
            }
            .grid > *:hover {
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 70vw;
                height: 70vw;
                z-index: 50;
            }
            .grid > *:not(:hover) {
                z-index: 10;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="grid">
            <div> 1 </div>
            <div> 2 </div>
            <div> 3 </div>
            <div> 4 </div>
            <div> 5 </div>
            <div> 6 </div>
            <div> 7 </div>
            <div> 8 </div>
            <div> 9 </div>
            <div> 10 </div>
            <div> 11 </div>
            <div> 12 </div>
            <div> 13 </div>
            <div> 14 </div>
            <div> 15 </div>
            <div> 16 </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Each row is given a left property using nth-child
Each column is given a top property using a nth-child trick to get only first 4n elements (where subsequent grabs overwrite the top)
This means all elements have both left and top set which means transition can be used on hover
This doesn't use the grid layout which means it's harder to expand or interact with this grid
There is no way (which I know) to selectivly turn on and off pointer-events on hover on and off which means you must hover off to select a different item.

### JS

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> grid expand </title>
        <style>
            .grid {
                border: 1px solid black;
                width: 80vw;
                height: 80vw;
                text-align: center;
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
                overflow: hidden;
                position: relative;
            }
            .grid > * {
                outline: 1px solid black;
                margin: 5vw;
                width: 10vw;
                height: 10vw;
                transition: transform 0.5s ease, width 0.5s ease, height 0.5s ease;
                background: white;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
            .grid > *.focus {
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                width: 70vw;
                height: 70vw;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function gridmove() {
                let children = event.target.children;
                let x = Math.round(event.x / event.target.clientWidth  * 4 - 0.5);
                let y = Math.round(event.y / event.target.clientHeight * 4 - 0.5);
                if (event.target.gridfocus) {
                    event.target.gridfocus.style.transform = `translate(0,0)`;
                    event.target.gridfocus.classList.remove("focus");
                }
                event.target.gridfocus = children[y * 4 + x];
                if (event.target.gridfocus) {
                    event.target.gridfocus.style.transform = `translate(-${x * 20}vw,-${y * 20}vw)`;
                    event.target.gridfocus.classList.add("focus");
                }
            }
            function gridleave() {
                if (event.target.gridfocus) {
                    event.target.gridfocus.style.transform = `translate(0,0)`;
                    event.target.gridfocus.classList.remove("focus");
                    event.target.gridfocus = undefined
                }
            }
            window.onload = () => {
                Object.values(document.getElementsByClassName("grid")).forEach(i => {
                    i.gridfocus = undefined;
                    i.onpointermove = gridmove;
                    i.onpointerleave = gridleave;
                });
            };
        </script>
        <div class="grid">
            <div> 1 </div>
            <div> 2 </div>
            <div> 3 </div>
            <div> 4 </div>
            <div> 5 </div>
            <div> 6 </div>
            <div> 7 </div>
            <div> 8 </div>
            <div> 9 </div>
            <div> 10 </div>
            <div> 11 </div>
            <div> 12 </div>
            <div> 13 </div>
            <div> 14 </div>
            <div> 15 </div>
            <div> 16 </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This uses JS to capture the mouse and add the `focus` class to whichever element should be focused which is then expanded using combined css and javascript transforming
This uses the grid layout which makes it easily scalable and customizable unlike CSS only.
Unlike CSS only, all elements shift around as no absolute positioning is being used which may not be preferable

### The perfect solution

The perfect solution would be to create elements with JS and keep everything in JS, which, although incredibly time consuming would work perfectly

Comment: Thanks, I took the time consuming way and used javascript  to position each div absolute.